# Evaluate $\int_{-8}^1\frac{dx }{x^{1/3}}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

The improper integral $\int_{-8}^1\frac{dx }{x^{1/3}}$ is evaluated as

$\lim_{a \to 0^-} \int _{-8}^a x^{-1/3} dx + \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int _{a}^1 x^{-1/3} dx=-9/2$

the graph of the function for negative x is below the x axis, so why are we not considering the first of the two integrals with a negative sign ?

$\lim_{a \to 0^-} \color{red}{-(\int _{-8}^a x^{-1/3} dx)} + \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int _{a}^1 x^{-1/3} dx=15/2$

Comment: if integral is area between the curve and the x axis, how can it be negative?

Comment: The curve is below the $x$ axis on $[-8,0)$.

Comment: A negative of a negative is a positive.

You cannot just invent a negative sign out of nowhere. Changing the sign is the same as multiplying by -1 and that -1 must arise from some logic, for some reason.

If the graph is under the x axis, then that part of the graph should and will have a negative sign, arising from the calcuations. Adding an extra negative sign out of the blue will make that part positive, incorrectly.

Comment: Before integrating a function it is better to define it. What is your definition of $x^{-1/3}$ for negative values of $x$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,$ x^{-1/3} $ exists for negative x and is negative

Comment: my assumption was that we consider area below the x axis with negative sign so that it becomes positive and adds with the area above the x axis, that's why i asked this question

Comment: Enlighten me please, because I see a function in $\mathbb{C}$ and not in $\mathbb{R}$ for $x<0$. Comparatively, if I try to plot $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ with, e.g. Mathematica, there is no curve fro negative $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing two things: calculating the integral and finding an area bounded by the graph and the $x$-axis on a certain interval.

If you integrate $\sin x$ on $[0,2\pi]$, you'll find zero:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin x \,\mbox{d}x = [-\cos x]_0^{2\pi} = 0$$
because the area under the graph and above the $x$-axis on $[0,\pi]$ is the same as the area above the graph and under the $x$-axis on $[\pi,2\pi]$. As a consequence of how integrals are defined, that area below the $x$-axis gets a minus-sign so they cancel and give $0$ as a result.

Now if you want to find the *area* bounded by the graph and the $x$-axis, you would manually add an extra minus-sign on the interval(s) where the graph is below the $x$-axis so all area is added up (of course in this case, you could just double the value on $[0,\pi]$ because of symmetry). In fact, you integrate $|\sin x|$ but in manual calculations, that would result in splitting and adding the minus:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin x| \,\mbox{d}x = \int_0^{\pi} \sin x \,\mbox{d}x \color{red}{-} \int_\pi^{2\pi} \sin x \,\mbox{d}x = \ldots = 1\color{red}{-} (-1) = 2$$

---

Back to your problem: if you simply need (or want) to calculate the integral, you get:
$$\int_{-8}^1\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}\,\mbox{d}x = \ldots = -\frac{9}{2}$$
If you want to find the area, you would integrate $|x^{-1/3}|$ and that would require adding the minus-sign on the interval $[-8,0)$ because the function is negative there:
$$\int_{-8}^1\left|\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}\right|\,\mbox{d}x = \color{red}{-}\int_{-8}^0\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}\,\mbox{d}x+ \int_{0}^1\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}\,\mbox{d}x =  \ldots = \frac{15}{2}$$

*Note*: in this case of an improper integral, the region 'bounded' by the graph of the function and the $x$-axis isn't *bounded*, since it stretches to infinity near the $y$-axis. However, if the improper integral converges, we still assign that finite value as *area* to this unbounded region.